# adding columns to dataframe based on values (time stamps)

Tags: python, pandas

there are two data frames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, '20150601T060000', 1, 3],
    [2, '20150601T061500', 1, 3],
    [3, '20150601T061500', 2, 3],
    [4, '20150601T063000', 2, 3],
    [5, '20150602T060000', 1, 3],
    [6, '20150602T061500', 1, 3],
    [7, '20150602T060000', 2, 3],
    [8, '20150602T061500', 2, 3],
    [9, '20150603T061500', 2, 3],
    ],columns='A B C D'.split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, '20150601T060000', '20150601T070000', 1, 0],
    [2, '20150601T061500', '20150601T070000', 2, 0],
    [3, '20150602T060000', '20150602T070000', 1, 0],
    [4, '20150602T060000', '20150602T070000', 2, 0],
    [5, '20150603T060000', '20150603T070000', 2, 0],
    ],columns='A B1 B2 C D'.split())
```

how to add columns B1 and B2 from df2 to df, so that C columns in both data frames have the same values and B column values are between B1 and B2?

The result should look like

```
   A                B  C  D               B1               B2
0  1  20150601T060000  1  3  20150601T060000  20150601T070000
1  2  20150601T061500  1  3  20150601T060000  20150601T070000
2  3  20150601T061500  2  3  20150601T061500  20150601T070000
3  4  20150601T063000  2  3  20150601T061500  20150601T070000
4  5  20150602T060000  1  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
5  6  20150602T061500  1  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
6  7  20150602T060000  2  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
7  8  20150602T061500  2  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
8  9  20150603T061500  2  3  20150603T060000  20150603T070000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
merged = pandas.merge( df, df2[['C','B1','B2']], on='C')
result = merged.query( 'B1 <= B <= B2')
#    A                B  C  D               B1               B2
#0   1  20150601T060000  1  3  20150601T060000  20150601T070000
#2   2  20150601T061500  1  3  20150601T060000  20150601T070000
#5   5  20150602T060000  1  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
#7   6  20150602T061500  1  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
#8   3  20150601T061500  2  3  20150601T061500  20150601T070000
#11  4  20150601T063000  2  3  20150601T061500  20150601T070000
#15  7  20150602T060000  2  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
#18  8  20150602T061500  2  3  20150602T060000  20150602T070000
#22  9  20150603T061500  2  3  20150603T060000  20150603T070000
```

### Update

If you want to sort by column `'A'` (as indicated in your desired result) then simply do `result = merged.query('B1<=B<=B2').sort('A')`

### Aside

I don't usually work with datetime columns, but it might make be safer to first convert these columns to datetime dtypes explicitly  before doing the query (plus the data will be easier to read)

```
df.B   = pandas.to_datetime(df.B)
df2.B1 = pandas.to_datetime(df2.B1)
df2.B2 = pandas.to_datetime(df2.B1)

# Repeating the merge/query above will yield the new result
#    A                   B  C  D                  B1                  B2
#0   1 2015-06-01 06:00:00  1  3 2015-06-01 06:00:00 2015-06-01 07:00:00
#2   2 2015-06-01 06:15:00  1  3 2015-06-01 06:00:00 2015-06-01 07:00:00
#5   5 2015-06-02 06:00:00  1  3 2015-06-02 06:00:00 2015-06-02 07:00:00
# ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Since you've changed your question since my original answer, you need a slightly more complex solution. Basically with this type of situation you need to

1. Convert timeseries `datetime` data type, and set as index
2. Resample so that you have regular intervals, and fill nulls
3. Left merge.
4. Mask by original times if desired.

Converting and resampling:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.B)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.B1)
df_resampled = df.resample('15min').fillna(method='pad')
df2_resampled = df2.resample('15min').fillna(method='pad')
```

Left-join on the indexes, as well as column C and pull back values from original index:

```
merged = pd.merge(df_resampled, df2_resampled, 
               left_index = True, right_index = True, on='C', how='left')
merged.ix[df.index]
Out[182]: 
                     A_x    C  D_x  A_y  D_y
B                                           
2015-06-01 06:00:00  1.0  1.0    3  1.0    0
2015-06-01 06:15:00  2.5  1.5    3  2.0    0
2015-06-01 06:15:00  2.5  1.5    3  2.0    0
2015-06-01 06:30:00  4.0  2.0    3  2.0    0
2015-06-02 06:00:00  6.0  1.5    3  3.5    0
2015-06-02 06:15:00  7.0  1.5    3  3.5    0
2015-06-02 06:00:00  6.0  1.5    3  3.5    0
2015-06-02 06:15:00  7.0  1.5    3  3.5    0
2015-06-03 06:15:00  9.0  2.0    3  5.0    0
```

Comment: your approach is interesting but it (fillna(method='pad')) implies that B column is ordered, if it's not so, the result will be wrong. F.e. if we switch row 1 with row 3, row 1 in the output will have B1,2 from C=1, not C=2 as expected

Comment: you can order the column first using `df = df.sort('B')` before running

Comment: still even when they are ordered, the mapping can be wrong, I've modified the description to show the case. with your solution 9 maps into 4, while it should be into 5.